# Shell Program Syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a shell script that will only execute if there are no arguments, but keep getting

```
Line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

when I run it in terminal. Any help would be appreciated.

```
if ($#argv != 0) then
    echo "You entered too many arguments!"

    exit 1

endif

echo "Correct number of arguments"

exit 40
```

Comment: How exactly do you run this in the terminal; what command(s) are you typing? And where is line 17? Your question should include the exact code that shows the problem *and* the exact error message you get when running that code.

Comment: `$#` is the number of arguments, not `$#argv`. And `( )` is not a math context.

Comment: And `endif` isn't valid syntax at all, hence the unexpected-end-of-file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `endif` is valid if the shell is a `csh` derivative. Just a guess, since the OP didn't specify... My `csh`-foo is intentionally extremely rusty, though...

Comment: Ahh. If it's csh, then we should be tagged as such.

Comment: Quoting from the description of [tag:shell]: "Without a specific tag, a portable (POSIX-compliant) solution should be assumed, though using 'posix' in addition or 'sh' instead is preferable". Thus, if the question is actually about csh, it should be added appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

`endif` is not valid shell syntax in any POSIX shell (`#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`, etc). This would be looking for `fi`, and never finding it, hence the unexpected end-of-file.

```
#!/bin/sh

if test "$#" -ne 0; then
    echo "You entered too many arguments!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It does not recognize the use of fi, it says argv0: command not found

Comment: @ElisabethPost, you'll note that the code I give doesn't have `argv0` in it anywhere. `$#` is the correct way to count argv entries in POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: @ElisabethPost, ...and if it's saying `argv0: command not found` rather than `unexpected end-of-file`, then it **is** actually recognizing the `fi`.